# Flow player problem

Tags: 7, files

I am using flow player on my site.
I am providing all possible fields but flow player is not playing any audio and video format.
please help.

Comment: did you check your browser's console for any errors?

Comment: yes! now i have over come the issue.mp3 is playing now. do u know about the audio formats which is supported on flow player??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer for Video format:**
As flow player does not support flash so that's why .wav extension's video can not play by flow player.

**Answere for audio format:**
Flow player mostly support mp3, ACC audio format.